# Properties of the $\text{lcm}(1,2 ,... n)$ function

Tags: number-theory, factorial

I was thinking the other day about the following function - a sort of prime factorial:
$$f(n) = \text{lcm}(1,2,\cdots,n) $$

Does this function have a name? Does it have any interesting properties analagous to $n!$ (e.g. a version of Sterling's formula?)

**EDIT** A previous version of this question asserted that $f(n)$ is equal to the primorial. As pointed out below, that is demonstrably false.

Comment: If you write $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,4)$ the result is $12$, but your product on the right would suggest the answer is $2 \cdot 3 = 6$? I think you might want to defined $f(n)$ as the product without the middle step of $\operatorname{lcm}$.

Comment: As Tom points out, you might want to include a factor of $p$ for every *power* of $p$.

Comment: Prime factorial? May be mean something like the [primorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) $n\#$, i.e. the product of all primes $\le n.$

Comment: It's the minimal exponent of the symmetric group $S_n$.

Comment: @lhf Cool observation!

Comment: http://oeis.org/A003418

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $\text{lcm}(1, \dots, n)$ is equal to $$e^{\psi(n)}$$

where $\psi$ is the [second Chebyshev function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function). Many proofs of the Prime Number Theorem proceed by first estimating the Chebyshev function, so you'll find a wealth of information on the Wikipedia page. To make a long story short, the least common multiple of the integers from $1$ to $n$ is approximately $e^n$.